# Runtime import with with multiple subdirectories in python

Tags: python, import, python-2.7, subdirectory

what is the best way to perform this type of import in python

file to be imported which is available in location one/ne_one/one_two/"

fielname : two.py

```
def foo():
    print "venkatttt!"
```

main file : main.py

```
s = __import__("one.one_one.one_two.two", fromlist=[])
function_class =  getattr(s,"one_one")
function_class1 =  getattr(function_class,"one_two")
function_class2 =  getattr(function_class1,"two")
print s
print function_class
print function_class1
print function_class2
function_class2.foo()
```

output of this code:

```
<module 'one' from '/opt/auto/src/ex/one/__init__.pyc'>
<module 'one.one_one' from '/opt/auto/src/ex/one/one_one/__init__.pyc'>
<module 'one.one_one.one_two' from '/opt/auto/src/ex/one/one_one/one_two/__init__.pyc'>
<module 'one.one_one.one_two.two' from '/opt/auto/src/ex/one/one_one/one_two/two.py'>
venkatttt!
```

i am looking out for the best way to perform this import

Comment: What's wrong with `import one.one_one.one_two.two`?

Comment: @phihag am trying to perform a runtime import so ill ot be able to use   import one.one_one.one_two.two

Answer (score 0):

From your output, I can see you already have `__init__.py` files in each subdirectory, therefore, you can simply `import` them:

```
$> from one.one_one.one_two.two import foo
$> foo()
```

If you want a handle for each module, you can import them separately:

```
$> import one.one_one as function_class
$> import one.one_one.one_two as function_class1
$> import one.one_one.one_two.two as function_class2
```

Finally, you can also define `__all__` in `one/__init__.py` and let this auto-imports happen automatically when `import one` is executed.

Comment: i dont want to load all classes..i get classes reference from database and then i have to load only that classes no all.

Comment: Then you can use `importlib.import_module`: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module